# Docker -it not start inside a cron script

Tags: docker, cron

I try to start a Docker command inside my crontab. When the docker run command has "-it", it won't start. I used cron to run a script. The script is started without problem. Here is it looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
Export all the evn variables
/usr/bin/docker run -it hello-world >> /tmp/log.log
```

If I run this command in console, it will give the "welcome to docker...". But has nothing output in this script. However if I remove the "-it", the hello-world run well in the script again.

I need run some Docker command with "-it", so they won't start in the cron script.

Comment: Found out error massages: input device is not TTY. Seems remove the -it from scripts, the docker commands run well now. So no need "-it" in the cron script.

Comment: `-t` is to pass tty to the docker container and a cron does not run with a tty. So that is the reason you don't need to use `-it`